# Google App Engine - YouTube Python Client Library Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the YouTube Data API client Library for Python. I have deployed my application on Google App Engine, the App Engine is able to import the library but following error is shown

`SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /Users/adityaborde/Python-projects/Gujarati Rasoi Bot/gujaratirasoi-bot/lib/httplib2/__init__.py on line 134, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

httplib2 file is part of the google-api-python-client library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you replace or copy paste some code that caused a replacement of single quotation mark with apostrophe? Please see this [article](https://prateekvjoshi.com/2013/02/15/non-ascii-character-syntax-error-in-python/) for some background information.

You could simply go to the _ init _.py file in question and see why line 134 is misread and see if you can fix it from there. If it's not incorrect in the file and it's just not being encoded properly, then adding this to the top of the .py file should work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: No I have not changed anything in the library

Comment: Yes, but it can happen whenever a file is copied or paste (maybe even from unzipping). If you go to the actual file in question... Do you see single quotes or apostrophes?

Comment: I added the Python encoding line, that works too if it's just an encoding issue.